# Detecting which parts flag AV

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, antivirus

Question: What's the best strategy to debug (hunt down the code) a .Net application that triggers an AV?

Details:
I'm trying to debug a .Net/Mono application that is being intercepted by AV (more detailed for my case AVG and NOD32).

I'd like to know what the best options or steps are for detecting on user's machines what might be the chunk of code that triggers these AVs to block the application's execution.

PS: To be very specific, the application uses Fody Costura to pack alle referenced assemblies (such as Mono.Sqlite.dll, custom assemblies, Sqlite drivers, image resources and other).

Comment: So, what do AVG/NOD32 have to say about what they found? Which signature got matched?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this false positive locally?

Comment: More to the point, what are you going to do when you find which bytes are triggering it? What if it's in one of the drivers or Mono?

Comment: @Spender: Still have to try and reproduce it locally. Need to setup a machine for that. Have to determine the signature as well, app just doesn't start up with users that us AVG Free edition, it doesn't even appear in the process list. We had this problem before, I know it's the AV (because when turned off it's ok).

Comment: @simonatrcl Then at least I know it's not my code triggering it. I just feel a bit in the dark now, and that's not healthy. If I ask users to turn off their AV, I need to be able to explain why.